# Не могу настроить nginx. По эндпоинту он отдает картинку, но когда заходишь на страницу приложения то там голый HTML, без статики

Tags: python, nginx, devops, fastapi, deploy

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
}

http {

    upstream backend {
        server site_moto_rafting_app:8000;
    }

    server {

        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /var/www/html/static/;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Логичный вопрос - а почему вы решили, что должен быть не голый HTML? В нём ссылки на статику вообще есть? Браузер вообще отправляет запросы по этим ссылкам? Если отправляет - доходят ли они до nginx вообще? Если доходят - какой ответ присылает nginx?